# Alternativas a SetPixel y Getpixel

Tags: c++, windows, codeblocks

he estado trabajando en los mapas de bits durante un buen tiempo, todo va muy bien asta que tengo qu imprimir los pixeles en la pantalla;para esto utilizo SetPixel pero es demasiado lento para cargar imagenes grandes y eso es un problema.

Directo al grano me gustaria una alternativa a SetPixel y GetPixel (que no sea putpixel ya que no se como utilizarlo) o una forma para optimizar la funcion de los pixeles.

Aqui el codigo:

```
void pixel(int x, int y){
       HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();
       HDC mydc = GetDC(myconsole);
       int COLOR=color_rgb(255, 255, 255);
           SetPixel(mydc ,x ,y ,COLOR );
       ReleaseDC(myconsole, mydc);
}
//Esta funcion esta sobrecargada
void pixel(int x, int y, int r, int g, int b){
       HWND myconsole = GetConsoleWindow();
       HDC mydc = GetDC(myconsole);
       int COLOR=color_rgb(r, g, b);
           SetPixel(mydc ,x ,y ,COLOR );
       ReleaseDC(myconsole, mydc);

}
```

Utilizo codeblocks y windows

Gracias

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si deseas "imprimir" un conjunto de pixeles en Win32, debes usar la funcion [StretchDIBits](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/wingdi/nf-wingdi-stretchdibits).

Ejemplo de uso:

```cpp
   BITMAPINFO bi = {0}; // Se inicia todo en ceros
   // bi.bmiColors -> No usamos este valor
   bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
   bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 32; // BGRA
   bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
   bi.bmiHeader.biWidth = widthDest;
   bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -heightDest; // El mapa de bits es un DIB de arriba hacia abajo y su origen es la esquina superior izquierda.
   bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;

   StretchDIBits(
      hDCDest,
      0, // x dest
      0, // y dest
      widthDest,
      heightDest,
      0, // X src
      0, // Y src
      widthSrc,
      heightSrc,

      pixels, // Array unidimensional que contiene los pixeles que desea pasar, en formato BGRA (para un correcto dibujado)
              // Este arreglo debe tener el tamaño: Width * Height * 4 (BGRA)

      &bi, // Un puntero a una estructura BITMAPINFO que contiene información sobre el DIB.

      DIB_RGB_COLORS, // La tabla de colores contiene valores RGB literales.

      SRCCOPY // Copia el rectángulo de origen directamente en el rectángulo de destino.
   );
```

Comment: Esto ha resuelto el problema, gracias

Comment: El arreglo de que tipo es?

Comment: El arreglo puede ser uint8_t (canal por elemento del arreglo) o uint32_t (la union de todo los canales, pero su tamaño solo debe ser width*height).

Comment: Es necesario el canal alfa?

Comment: Para dibujar en Win32, si es necesario

Comment: Y de que tipo de variable son los datos como de tipo  entero o hexadecimal por ejem. arreglo={0, 0, 1, 0...} o  arreglo={0xfd, 0xfre...}

Comment: El arreglo son numeros normales (con su maximo y minimo valor del tipo de variable, como ya te explique puede ser uint8_t o uint32_t). Te recomiendo que crees un bitmap con un arreglo de pixeles y "jueges" con él para que entiendas mejor como funciona

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre crear un bitmap de color blanco,
Aqui el codigo de ejemplo:

```
   BITMAPINFO bi = {0}; // Se inicia todo en ceros
   // bi.bmiColors -> No usamos este valor
   bi.bmiHeader.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);
   bi.bmiHeader.biBitCount = 24; // BGRA
   bi.bmiHeader.biCompression = BI_RGB;
   bi.bmiHeader.biWidth = 10;
   bi.bmiHeader.biHeight = -10; // El mapa de bits es un DIB de arriba hacia abajo y su origen es la esquina superior izquierda.
   bi.bmiHeader.biPlanes = 1;
    uint8_t bits[10*10*3+30]={255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
    255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
     255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
      255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
       255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255,
        255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255, 255};

   StretchDIBits(
      mydc,
      0, // x dest
      0, // y dest
      10,
      10,
      0, // X src
      0, // Y src
      10,
      10,

      bits, // Array unidimensional que contiene los pixeles que desea pasar, en formato BGRA (para un correcto dibujado)
              // Este arreglo debe tener el tamaño: Width * Height * 4 (BGRA)
      &bi, // Un puntero a una estructura BITMAPINFO que contiene información sobre el DIB.

      DIB_RGB_COLORS, // La tabla de colores contiene valores RGB literales.

      SRCCOPY // Copia el rectángulo de origen directamente en el rectángulo de destino.
   );
```